# SimpleImage > TypeError: canvas.getContext is not a function

Tags: javascript

I was just trying to use SimpleImage javascript library, but I got this error :

```
TypeError: canvas.getContext is not a function
SimpleImage.js:14:18
```

In the SimpleImage library line 14 their is

```
this.context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

I import SimpleImage library in the header with :

```
<script async="" src="SimpleImageLocation"></script>
```

And I try to create a new class with :

```
var smplImg = new SimpleImage("ImageLocation");
```

or

```
var input = document.getElementById("sourceImage");
var smplImg = new SimpleImage(input);
```

I downloaded Simple image via bower and my browser is Firefox 62.0.2 on Mac OS 10.

What can I do to overpass this error ?

Comment: Do you know what piece of your code calls SimpleImage? If so please add it to the question.
If not have you tried stepping through your code with the browser Javascript debugger?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I put `<script async="" src="SimpleImageLocation"></script>` in the header and I call it by `var smplImg = new SimpleImage("ImageLocation");` or `var input = document.getElementById("sourceImage");
        var smplImg = new SimpleImage(input);`

Comment: The canvas is most likely 'undefined'. This can be due number of reasons: missing element, misspelling etc. Can you please provide this logic as well ?

Comment: I put a fonction to test if my file exist or not=; It does exist.

Comment: If you are talking about [this lib](https://github.com/wadefagen/SimpleImage), then their *readme* states that "*Each SimpleImage requires an HTML canvas,*" (that you'll pass as the first argument of the Constructor). `"ImageLocation"` is a string, and therefor not an HTML Canvas, and even though we have no clue what #sourceImage is, it certainly is not an HTML Canvas element either.

Comment: Thanks I better understand. So I create a new canvas which I put as argument for `document.getElementById("canvas");` .
Now the SimpleImage is well called.

Comment: And now I see that I was using two different documentation : the original one and one from a fork. So I better understand why I can't use some fonctions. :p